# Changing Download Percent in Listview in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview, webclient

I m displaying download percent of downloading file in listview using DownloadProgressChanged event of webclient.

The code works perfectly fine when I display "Overallpercent" in label, but it gives me "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" error after few loops if I try to display same in listview.

My code for changing the listview subitem is below

```
Private Sub downloadprogressruntimemade(currentimage As Integer, totalimages As Integer, li As ListViewItem, indexnumberforlv As Integer, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)

        Dim li1 As ListViewItem = li
        Dim overallpercent = Math.Round((currentimage / totalimages) * 100, 2) + Math.Round(e.ProgressPercentage / 1 / totalimages, 2)
        li1.SubItems.Insert(indexnumberforlv, New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(Nothing, overallpercent & " %"))
        refreshcontrol(LVsessionnotfound)
               
End Sub
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The first argument to the ListViewSubItem constructor cannot be Nothing.  Pass li1 instead.  Not the only bug in this code, inserting repeatedly doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why are you redeclaring `li` as `li1`? Also, I suggest you set breakpoints to see which variable is Nothing when it cannot be Nothing. That should help you find the root cause.

Comment: @HansPassant is there any other way than not inserting? I want to update the value to newer one(like changing 57% to 63%).. I m not a hard code developer, so I have very less knowledge in this.

Comment: @Audiopolis I was not redeclaring it earlier, but when I started to get error, I thought of doing that.. I know it wont make sense.. But since this in progresschanged event of weblclient handler, it keeps getting newer values, so I thought of doing it.
My breakpoints are always on, but I was unable to find anything except that it is related to listview, because the same code is working great with label instead of listview

Comment: @HansPassant, can you help me in identifying any other bug in the code? It would help me the long run.. Also, I have assigned overallpercent as decimal, if thats what you were pointing at..

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the bug, Thanks to @Hans Passant for mentioning that insert would be wrong way to do this.. I changed insert to `li.SubItems(1).Text = overallpercent & " %"` and it works great.